# Why is react-bootstrap not working with reactjs 0.14.3?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've just integrated both new versions of

- react-bootstrap 0.28.1
- reactjs 0.14.3

via CDN, but i can't get react-bootstrap to work if I use `reactjs 0.14.3`. If I downgrade to version `0.13.3` everything works fine.

Does anyone have a clue what has happened? Naming issue?

**UPDATE ---------------**

Actually it is not reacts itself but the DOM render! With the older version you've had to use `JSXTransformer (0.13.3)` and now this one is deprecated and one should use `react-dom` instead.

Is there a solution to this? How could I use the latest version of reactjs and react-bootstrap?

Comment: "Not working" is a really vague way to present a problem. What really happens ? Do you get a runtime error? (if so please provide a stack trace), do you get inconsistent behaviors ? Does the UI breaks ? (if so please provide some screenshots) .

Comment: It's quite likely to be related to an API change from React 0.13 to 0.14. React usually deprecates a feature before removing it. So make sure your 'working' 0.13 app isn't producing any console warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!
I've just been trying out different things and it seems like that since reactjs version `0.14.0` there is no JSXTransformer any more and this seems to be my problem.

I've got no console warnings and the UI does not break. The sample script simply produces no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

It's actually just the way I was referencing the source code. Instead of

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.1/react-bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">

   // React Code

   React.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("example"));
</script>
```

I use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.1/react-bootstrap.js"></script>


<script type="text/babel">

   // React Code

   ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("example"));
</script>
```

and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the copy & pasted code snippet.